# Is this grossly incomplete code okay?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope

[Shortening code to create a JFrame](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37622/how-can-i-improve-my-game-project)

The user has working code (I assume), but they haven't even started writing the logic for their game. They've just instantiated Java's version of a main window/frame.

I feel like this is the same as me asking, "Please review my OS Kernel" and then all I give you is this:

```
int main (void)
{
    return 0 ;
}
```

For my answer, I did my best to explain possible next steps, but there's not really much to advise on.

I'm not advocating that code submitted for review must be complete, but I think there should be a decent amount of progress. Otherwise we can only give design tips that may be better off being posted on Programmers Stack Exchange.

Comment: Close it as "off topic". "Working code" means "solves someone's problem", not "it compiles".

Comment: @Jamal The title seems really condescending now! =(

Comment: @jliv902: Well, it sort of was from the start.  You're free to make it less-condescending while still making your point.

Comment: Hmm, that's not even a very good start for a kernel. Who would it return to? :-)

Comment: @svick So then my custom Kernel code *does* need reviewing? =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not *quite* as pointless as `return 0` — there is *some* code to be reviewed, and I'd leave it open in case someone wants to review it.  I'd rather not trigger any close-vs.-reopen wars.  (Who knows, there might be a shortcut or a hidden bug worth mentioning.)

I've downvoted it, though, for being an uninteresting and poorly formulated question.

Answer (score 3):

After thinking it over, here are my conclusions:

1. There is, in fact, some code that can be reviewed.
2. I believe the topic-creator posted the code in good faith. He was probably just wanting to make sure he was starting things correctly. His reasoning was probably along the lines of, *"If I make a design mistake this early, it will cost me dearly later on."*
3. I think my real problem was that the code provided did not reflect what the topic title question was asking about. There is no way to improve a game that does not exist and has not been written. Now that the topic title has changed to a more accurate description of the problem, I have no qualms about the topic.